# How can I monitor my Application server or Database server from Jmeter scripts ? Can we check CPU , memory utilization, etc?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

**I need to know till what extend we can analyze our Application using Apache Jmeter.**

My script creation is complete. Paramatrized & Correlated. Now I need a deep understanding of Analysis.

Earlier, I just use to focus on Response time, Standard deviation, throughput, etc.

But now my boss wants me to do more analysis. Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these Samplers from JMeter-plugins project:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DbMon/
- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/

Comment: Can you please give me some more suggestions ?

Comment: I need to find the CPU, MEMORY utilization and other advance details which can help me to point out the bottlenecks.
Also please give me some baby steps :)

Answer (score 0):

Correctly still divide the tasks and means to solve them. If you need to monitor the parameters of the server utilization - then it needs to use the appropriate means, for example, zabbix. If you need to understand how much resources consumes your server applications - it is necessary to refer to the appropriate monitoring tools, plug-ins, such as Zorka for WebSphere in zabbix.